# solr indexing content for large files(even greater than a GB)

Tags: java, search, solr, lucene, full-text-search

I am newbie to Solr Indexing. I was looking at various ways to index files larger than a GB (Can be more than that). I have tried Apache Tika to index files. It works well if the size is not more than 30MB. For files greater than that, I get out of memory exception in spite of increasing the memory size to 4096MB (Some blogs have suggested using a Apache Tika for large files indexing to avoid memory issues. I have not tried that yet). I wanted to know if there are any better ways to index large files. I have read about Data Import Handler(DIH) but not sure how to integrate it with the existing Solr setup. Does anyone know how to go about DIH. I have spent days together to integrate but doesn't seem to be working. Step by step process right from installing DIH until processing some sample files would help a lot. If there are any other ways to index large files, please advise on that as well.

I am basically trying to implement search functionality in one of my web portals where users can access files from various file servers. He should be able to check which files have the contents he types in the search bar. I'll be running a job everyday to pick changed/new files and re index them.

Comment: I downloaded Tika and tried indexing some PDF's, word docs etc..It worked well for files upto 30MB. But takes too much processing time.

Answer (score 0):

Solr uses Tika under the covers for binary (PDF, Word) formats. So, if it fails for Tika directly, it will most probably not work in Solr either. I would make a simple use case that shows a problem and ask at the Tika mailing list. Once it is solved for Tika, you can see whether/how that solution can fit into Solr itself.

You may also want to look at a dedicated client that runs on a separate machine with extra-large memory and converts those files to the Tika-extracted versions in a job queue fashion.